# Unity how to play video on plane without being affected by lighting

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, vuforia

I'm trying to play a video in Unity. I figured it can be done with the VideoPlayer, so I put a VideoPlayer with a RenderTexture on a Plane and created a Material for the Plane that utilises this texture to render the video.

This works fine.

However, the video appears way to bright compared to the original content. You can see this on these pictures:

[image: Movie in Unity]
[image: Original]

I found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KG2aq_CY7pU which looked promising but afterall didn't change the result, the video still appears way too bright.

Here is how I configured the Material
[image: Material config]

This is how the GO structure is set up

[image: GO structure]

Config of the VideoPlayer
[image: VideoPlayer config]

and the config of the Plane
[image: Plane config]

How can I play the video just "normal" like I would see it in VLC Player or any other video player?

P.S. Not sure if it is important but I'm working on an AR Project with Vuforia, where the video is supposed to be played on the image target. But it makes no difference if I play the video on the target or in a scene in Unity, it is the same effect.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the emission. Instead rather simply use a Shader that is Unlit (basically meaning no shadows, it is always fully illuminated).

In your case you can simply use the built-in shader

`Unlit` -> `Texture` and should be fine,